# Unrideable boats

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a map in which the player controls a boat in all four directions, the boat has got the NoGravity tag but the problem is I am incapable of stopping the player from riding the boat, by riding it the map is hardly a challenge as you can easily maneuver in all 4 directions and have no need for the parkour within the map, is there any way to make a boat unrideable by a player whilst still allowing them to stand on it, so not using zombies to hold the space as they will push the player off. P.S I am making this in 1.10 pre.

Comment: Just to be clear: You want a boat that a player can sit in, but not move using the regular boat controls? Or do you want the boat to be a platform that a player can't even enter?

Answer (score 5):

You can insert two entities into the boat's `Passengers` list at the same depth to remove the ability for the player to enter it.

```
/summon Boat ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"armor_stand",Invisible:1b,Marker:1b},{id:"armor_stand",Invisible:1b,Marker:1b}]}
```

Armor stands themselves do not push the player. The `Marker` tag will also remove the bounding box of the armor stand to prevent interaction with the player (such as giving the armor stand items).

Comment: I suggest you explain the `Marker` tags here, as OP was worried about being pushed out of the boat by entities.

Comment: @MrLemon Done, though armor stands do not push players away without it.